# AngularJS ngRoute not loading when directly accessing URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I have just start working with AngularJS but have an extensive background with JavaScript, PHP, HTML, CSS, etc. I have a basic template put together and everything works fine, when you start at '/'. However, if I tried to load '/contact' or any other page instead of starting at '/' I get a 404 not found. Now, I understand the basics as to why: AngularJS loads different content based on the templates via AJAX so the page never changes. The question: how do I fix this? I cannot be the first one to have this issue but I did some Googling and couldn't find any help.

**File: index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="alertBlaze">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AlertBlaze</title>
    <link href="stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AlertBlaze</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/platform">Platform</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/app.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**File: app.min.js**

```
var alertBlaze = angular.module('alertBlaze', ['ngRoute']);

alertBlaze.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);

alertBlaze.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/platform', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/platform.html',
        controller  : 'platformController'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
});

alertBlaze.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

});

alertBlaze.controller('platformController', function($scope) {

});

alertBlaze.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {

});

alertBlaze.controller('contactController', function($scope) {

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share some code so that we can see what might be the issue.

Comment: My bad! I forgot, you can't really just view the source code with Angular. Updated with code!

Comment: Your code looks fine and http://alertblaze.com/ seems to work correctly...

Answer (score 0):

I think problems in **$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');**

If you can go to http://alertblaze.com/contact you catch 404, but if you can go to http://alertblaze.com/#/contact - it's success.

try to change

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

to the

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

or remove

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

and change your routing with **#/**

Comment: You are correct! I posted an answer which was adding rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so yeah apparently the issue is exactly what Tara's said it was however, I want the pound sign remove for cleaner URL's so I added Apache Rewrite Rules to rewrite everything to index.html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Add the above as a rewrite and everything will work!